# How to modify the frames when recording and save the changes, and then save the video as mp4 file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter

In my project, I need to capture the frame when video started.And I capture it from the delegate

`"- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection`",and use `"appendPixelBuffer:newPixBuffer withPresentationTime:tmpTime"` to save the modified frame. These are ok! But, when I finisheded recording once, the avassetwriter's status can change to completed, but the mp4 file can not be save.

Here is my some code :

1. configueration:

   ```
   -(void)configRecording:(NSURL*)fileUrl
   ```

   {
       NSError* error;

   ```
   _recordingFilePath = fileUrl;

   NSDictionary *videoCleanApertureSettings = @{
                                                AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:SCREEN_WIDTH],
                                                AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:SCREEN_WIDTH],
                                                AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                                                AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                                                };

   NSDictionary *videoCompressionSettings = @{
                                              AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2000000.0],
                                              AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
                                              AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline30,
                                              AVVideoCleanApertureKey: videoCleanApertureSettings,
                                              };

   NSDictionary* videoSetting = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:SCREEN_WIDTH],AVVideoWidthKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:SCREEN_WIDTH],AVVideoHeightKey,
                                 videoCompressionSettings,AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                                 AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,AVVideoScalingModeKey,
                                 nil];

   _avassetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:fileUrl fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&error];

   // Add the audio input
   AudioChannelLayout acl;
   bzero( &acl, sizeof(acl));
   acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono;
   NSDictionary* audioOutputSettings = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless ], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 16 ], AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                          [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                          [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( acl ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                          nil ];

   _avassetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSetting];
   _avassetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
   _audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:audioOutputSettings];
   _audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
   _avassetAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:_avassetWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:videoSetting];


   if ([_avassetWriter canAddInput:_avassetWriterInput] ) {

       [_avassetWriter addInput:_avassetWriterInput];

   }

   if ([_avassetWriter canAddInput:_audioWriterInput]) {
       [_avassetWriter addInput:_audioWriterInput];
   }

   BOOL canOutput = [_avassetWriter canApplyOutputSettings:videoSetting forMediaType:AVFileTypeMPEG4];
   NSLog(@"can out put := %d", canOutput);
   ```

   }
2. this is my start recording function:

   [_avassetWriter startWriting];
     [_avassetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

3.this is the way to modify the frame:

```
 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        int faceTrackResult = [faceTracker startFacialTracking:pixelBuffer
                                             startFaceTracking:YES
                                             withFaceRectangle:_faceRect
                                                 withRollAngle:_rollAngle];

        CVPixelBufferRetain(pixelBuffer);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_trackerView drawSceneWithBackground:pixelBuffer];
            CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
        });

        if (cameraView.isRecording == YES) {
            CMTime tmpTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
            [cameraView getLastRecordingTime:tmpTime];
            //开始捕捉视频帧
                CGImageRef curFrameRef = [cameraView getImageRef:self.trackerView.frame];
                CVPixelBufferRef newPixBuffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:curFrameRef];


                if (cameraView.avassetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting && cameraView.isRecording == YES) {

                    BOOL result = [cameraView.avassetAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:newPixBuffer withPresentationTime:tmpTime];
                    NSLog(@"result := %d; status := %ld", result, (long)cameraView.avassetWriter.status);
                }
        }
    }
```

4. This is my stop recording function:

   -(void)stopRecording
       {
           WS(weakSelf);

   ```
       [_avassetWriterInput markAsFinished];
       [_avassetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime: lastSimple_Time];
       if (_avassetWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted) {
           NSLog(@"error := %@", _avassetWriter.error);
       }

       self.isRecording = NO;

       [_avassetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{

           if (_avassetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed) {
               NSLog(@"error := %@", _avassetWriter.error);
           }

           if (weakSelf.recordDelegate && [weakSelf.recordDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishRecording:)]) {
               [weakSelf.recordDelegate finishRecording:weakSelf.recordingFilePath];
           }
       }];
   }
   ```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: You should really take the time to format the code. This looks like something I could help you with.

Comment: sorry，first time to editor. Now I formatted it.

Comment: I saved my mp4 file in the Documents foldor.